# Nullpointer Exception (Derby, JDBC)

Tags: java, exception, jdbc, nullpointerexception, derby

Hy!!

My error code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at lesebank.Konto.getKontofromID(Konto.java:39)
        at lesebank.Main.main(Main.java:18)
SQL EXCEPTIONJava Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Method:

```
Konto konto = new Konto ();
        Statement s = dbconn.getSt();
        try
        { //in the next line the error occurs
           s.execute("select id,inhaberin,ktostd,habenzinsen,notiz from Konto where id = " +id);
           ResultSet set = s.getResultSet();
           if (set.next())
           {
               konto.setId(set.getInt(1));
               konto.setId_inhaberin(set.getInt(2));
               konto.setKtostd(set.getDouble(3));
               konto.setHabenzinsen(set.getDouble(4));
               konto.setNotiz(set.getString(5));
               return konto;
           }
        }
        catch (SQLException ex)
        {
            System.out.print(ex.getMessage());
        }


        return null;
```

DBConn:

```
public class DBConnection {

   private String url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Bank";
   private Connection conn;
   private Statement st;

    public DBConnection() {
        try
        {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(this.url, "test", "test");
            st = conn.createStatement();

        }
        catch (SQLException ex)
        {
           System.out.print("SQL EXCEPTION");
        }
    }

    public Statement getSt() {
        return st;
    }
```

Database:
[image: Database]

Please help

Comment: Could you point out which line is line 39? So we can tell exactly which line throws the exception.

Comment: If you fixed it yourself and the answer is not of general interest, then please delete the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Very Bad(tm):

```
public DBConnection() {
    try
    {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(this.url, "test", "test");
        st = conn.createStatement();

    }
    catch (SQLException ex)
    {
       System.out.print("SQL EXCEPTION");
    }
}
```

Do *not* catch and ignore exceptions like this. There are there for a *very* good reason.  In this case, if your constructor fails due to an exception, the whole `DbConnection` object is rendered useless, since the `st` field will be null. Yet because the code that instantiated `DbConnection` has no idea this has happened, you go on to use it, and end up with the null-pointer exception.

If `DbConnection`'s constructor triggers an exception, you need to *throw* that exception out of the constructor, forcing your code to deal with the exception:

```
public class DBConnection {

   private static final String URL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Bank";
   private final  Connection conn;
   private final Statement st;

    public DBConnection() throws SQLException {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, "test", "test");
        st = conn.createStatement();
    }

    public Statement getSt() {
        return st;
    }
}
```

Note also the `final` fields. This gives you a compile-time guarantee that *something* will be assigned to those fields.

Comment: Another Bad Thing of such a `DBConnection` setup is that the connection cannot be closed from outside and this is thus very prone to resource leaking. I'd throw it all away and just acquire the connection/statement inside the very same `try` block as the query needs to be executed. Refactor at highest only the `getConnection()` call. This enables you to close them properly in `finally` block.

Answer (score 0):

Please check that `dbconn.getSt()` is not returning `null`. <strike>What is `getSt()`, anyway; anything like `createStatement()`?</strike> Now that I see your edit, it is likely that your DBConn class is not successful in its call to `createStatement()`.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite able to test right now, but I would sugest you make your `DBConnection.getSt()` method return a brand new Statement object, instead of reusing the same one over and over. Would be something like:

```
public Statement getSt() {
    return conn.createStatement();
}
```

Remember to close your statement after using it.